# How to work on an unchecked branch with git?

Tags: git

I wish to make a tool storing things in a branch that is not checked out, so it transparently make adjustements while you are working on your current branch.

Stuff I want to do :

- add files;
- make commits;
- resolve conflicts;
- push.

what commands would let me do that ?

Right now I'm doing this by cloning the local repo in /tmp, checking out the secret branch, and working on that. I wonder if I can do it without this trick.

Comment: How does the secret branch know how it should change?

Comment: Unless you're in a detached HEAD state, you're definitely on a branch.  I'm a bit confused at what it is you're attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

Under the `contrib/workdir` directory of Git's source code, you will find a  git command named `git new-workdir`.

This command allow you to work simultaneously on several branches side by side.
What the function does is simply creating a shallow copy of your `git` folder (type tree .git in the new folder to see where it actually points to) and you will see that it points to the original git folder.
In the new folder you can create new commits, branches and more, and you will see it in all of your `new-workdir` folders since they share the "same" git repo.

## Demo: (Unix)

1. add the `contrib/workdir` to your path
2. set execution flags to the `git-new-workdir`
3. navigate to your current git repository

   ```
   git new-workdir . my_new_path 
   cd my_new_path
   tree .git ( you should see links to the original git repository)
   git checkout -b new_branch
   git branch (your new branch is listed)
   cd original_path
   git branch (the new branch is listed but the current branch is the original branch)
   ```

:-)

[image: Here is a screenshot of the 2 diffent branches]

Git 2.5 will contain a feature allowing you to have multiple working directory without using this script (`git checkout --to=$path`).